# Null check operator error when widget testing using Flutter Modular's context.watch extension

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter, flutter-modular

I'm using the Flutter Modular package for the first time and might be doing something wrong, but I'm getting a `Null check operator used on a null value` error any time I run a widget test with a widget that uses Flutter Modular's `context.watch` extension method.

The error always reads something like:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building DailyBalanceGraph(dirty, state:
_DailyBalanceGraphState#87329):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  DailyBalanceGraph
  DailyBalanceGraph:file:///Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/lib/modules/home/widgets/home_page_activity_display.dart:36:21

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _ModularInherited.of (package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/widgets/modular_app.dart:105:32)
#1      ModularWatchExtension.watch (package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/widgets/modular_app.dart:193:30)
#2      _DailyBalanceGraphState.build (package:cash4cast/modules/home/widgets/daily_balance_graph.dart:94:17)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (39 frames)
#48     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#49     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#50     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1243:37)
#51     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1228:20)
#52     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2600:19)
#53     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1221:12)
#54     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:349:23)
#55     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1997:59)
#56     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
#57     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1997:14)
#58     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:338:5)
#59     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:484:5)
#60     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:250:17)
#61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#62     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#63     _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver_fill.dart:167:11)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#65     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#66     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#67     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#68     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1731:7)
#69     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#70     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1131:23)
#71     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#72     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#73     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#74     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:995:9)
#77     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:71:41)
#78     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:982:27)
#79     WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:668:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided 3 frames from dart:async and package:stack_trace)
```

`flutter --version` output:

```
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.gitFramework • revision 7e9793dee1 (3 weeks ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600Engine • revision bd539267b4Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Flutter Modular version ^4.4.0+1

A short example of the call that is failing would be something like:

```
class Counter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count {
    return _count;
  }

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class ConsumerClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConsumerClass();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // when debugging the test, it will fail on this line; the context is not null, but 
    // it will fail inside the .watch call without ever entering the Counter class
    final int count = context.watch<Counter>().count;

    return Text(count.toString());
  }
}
```

Then, in a test file:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {

  setUp(() {
    initModule(AppModule());
  });

  testWidgets('should instantiate', (tester) async => {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ConsumerClass(),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  });
}
```

The only solution I have found is to completely remove all references to `context.watch` and instead wrap my widgets in an `AnimatedBuilder`, resulting in something like this:

```
class ConsumerClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConsumerClass();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: Modular.get<Counter>(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        final int count = Modular.get<Counter>().count;
        return Text(count.toString()),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the test files in the Flutter Modular project, I discovered that they are wrapping everything inside a `ModularApp` when first pumping their widget tree.

For example, where I was using:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidgetUnderTest());
```

I should have been using:

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  ModularApp(
    module: Module(),
    child: MyWidgetUnderTest(),
  ),
);
```

I implemented this in some of my tests and it seems to work as expected!

It also seems safe to use the default `Module()` constructor as the `module` property (as opposed to a custom testing module or a mocked module), but I have asked the team for more information/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Modular package but I am pretty sure, it's because you didn't provide the `Counter` to your `ConsumerClass`. With packages like Provider, for example, you would wrap the parent of your `ConsumerClass` with a `CounterProvider` that would provide an instance of `Counter` to the consumer class, I assume there is something similar for the Flutter Modular Package.